# Convert 9.78043976074e+12 to String Python

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I saw this answered for PHP, but I was wondering if there's a conversion for Python 2.7 anywhere.

It should convert this:

```
9.78043976074e+12
```

To this:

```
9780439760737
```

Thanks!

Comment: You subtract 3 by magic?

Comment: you can do `int(number)`

Comment: Sorry, the original 9.78043976074e+12 number is what is displaying in Excel. What I want to do is convert it to the string that actually exists in the cell: 9780439760737. This represents an ISBN which Excel apparently converts to the "e+#" for reasons I don't know.

Comment: It looks like this is more of an Excel issue than anything to do with Python. I inserted a tick before the number in each cell, then selected "Text" as the cell/column formatting, loaded the saved xls in Python and it's now displaying as desired. Please feel free to delete this whole question if it doesn't help or is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Like this, to convert to string:

```
a = 9.78043976074e+12
print "%d" % a
>> 9780439760740
```

or just round to integer:

```
print int(a)
```

Comment: Why is this being dowvoted...?

Comment: No idea why it is being down-voted *or* up-voted.

Comment: @AndrewClark Because that is what OP is asking for (in the title, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Or like this?

```
a='%.1f' % 9.78043976074e+12
type(a)
>> str
a
>>'9780439760740.0'
```

Or if it is all integers , `'%.0f' % 9.78043976074e+12` would be fine.